# Office.js comment identifier

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js

I am inserting comment in Word via below snippet. However, I am not clear where/how to insert a custom ID (or any other identifier) in order to search for for this comment later on. Any ideas?

```
async function insertContentControls() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let range = context.document.getSelection();
 
    await context.sync();
 
    range.insertOoxml(
      '<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512" ><pkg:xmlData ><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" ><Relationship Id="rId1" Type = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData ></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/comments" Target="comments.xml" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p><w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/><w:r><w:t>It was selected text!</w:t></w:r><w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/><w:r><w:commentReference w:id="0"/></w:r></w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage" pkg:name="/word/comments.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:comments xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:comment xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:id="0"><w:p><w:r><w:t>Comment</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:comment></w:comments></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/comments.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>',
      "Replace"
    ); 
     
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```